# Turning the primary monitor off using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, win32gui

How can the primary monitor on Windows (starting with 7) be turned on/off?

- WM_SYSCOMMAND/SC_MONITORPOWER is of no value due to power management if password activated and other negative effects - just try nircmd with with 'password required on display activation' option turned on in Energy Settings;
- SetVCPFeature w. 0xD6 fails on laptops due to I2C error;
- ChangeDisplaySettings(Ex) does not produce any reasonable results;
- SetDisplayConfig fails for primary display ( i.e., position 0/0 ).
  Any ideas?

Comment: Related question: [Programmatically changing the “presentation display mode”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790287/programmatically-changing-the-presentation-display-mode)