# Move or hide UWP app window to another display

Tags: .net, windows, uwp

Is it possible to move UWP app main window to another display? I'm using ProjectionManager to project to connected display:

```
+--------------+                         +-------------------+
|   MainPage   | -> ProjectionManager -> |   ProjectedPage   |
+--------------+                         +-------------------+
```

where MainPage is the main window (app entry point), and ProjectedPage is secondary window projected by the ProjectionManager to connected display. However, I would like to hide main window (on the main display) while projecting, or just move whole app to connected display.

I could not find any APIs, so my question is, is this supported?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> could not find any APIs, so my question is, is this supported?

This is not what the ProjectionManager API should do, please see the [Guidelines for projection manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn495078.aspx)

> Projection manager lets you project a **separate** window of your app
>   on another screen...

Your requirement should be changing the project display mode to "Second screen only". In the traditional desktop application, we have solution in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790287/programmatically-changing-the-presentation-display-mode)

Currenly there is no such API supported in UWP app. Please submit a feedback in [Windows developer feedback site](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform). For the same feature request item, please vote it.

If you just need to side-loading an UWP app, we can consider using Brokered Windows Runtime Components by following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps)

Comment: I never said I want to use ProjectionManager API for this, I said I'm using ProjectionManager in certain way, and was asking whether there is another API that would provide what I need. I don't want to change system projection of the the screen (second screen only), I just need to hide my applications window (and keep the screen on).