Is there interface to set the projection mode in UWP appliction?
I need to create an application to implement mirror casting.
Refer to Microsoft official sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/Projection/cs  And this is an UWP application, which could make projection to another wireless display like what Windows System does.
But as for changing the projection mode, e.g. Duplicate, Extend, I only know the Windows System way. That is by pressing Ctrl+P and selecting the projection mode.
I want to know is there API to set the projection mode?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790287/programmatically-changing-the-presentation-display-mode
